# Media query ipad vs iphone4

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using the media query in css to differentiate iphone and ipad

Here's my code:

```
/* iphone 3 */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation:portrait) { ... }

/* iphone 4 */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 640px) and (max-device-width : 960px) and (orientation:portrait) { ... }

/*iPad styles*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) { ... }

/* i have the same for landscape */
```

Now I have a resolution conflict, the iphone 4 use the same resolution as the ipad and vice versa.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Modify your iPhone 4 media query to target high density pixel displays (retina = iPhone4)

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px), screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation:portrait) { ... }
```

---

Didn't notice you reopened the question with an expansion so here is a reworked answer to target both iphones (3 and 4) and ipads.

Breakdown of what you should expect:

- On regular browsers you should get the `teal` background color.
- `orange` on an ipad (landscape).
- `black` on an ipad (portrait)
- `red` on an iphone 4 (portrait)
- `pink` on an iphone 4 (landscape)
- `green` on regular smartphones, e.g Androids (landscape)
- `purple` on a regular smartphone (portrait)

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:teal;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    body {
        background-color:yellow;
    }
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
    body {
        background-color:orange;
    }
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
    body {
        background-color:black;
    }
}

/* iPhone 4 - (portrait) ---------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation:portrait),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)  and (orientation:portrait){
    body {
        background-color:red;
    }
}

/* iPhone 4 - (landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation:landscape), screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation:landscape){
    body {
        background-color:pink;
    }
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px)
and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color:green;
    }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
    body {
        background-color:purple;
    }
}`<!-- language-all: lang-css -->
```

I reformatted the `@media` queries found in this fine [article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) over at CSS-tricks to comply to some iphone4-specific bits, but overall this media query set should cover both iphones (3 and 4 with separate media queries) and ipads as well.

Here is a demo you can try in your i-devices.

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/SpbC3/4/show/

And you can also try out the queries over at http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ to see how they stack up. One thing though, the screenfly site does not differentiate between iphone 3 and 4 because regular browsers skip the `webkit` only `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5` pixel ratio count so you will get better results testing it out in your actual device.

Comment: Lets step back for a second, try this in your iphone 3 and 4 http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/GeUL9/1/show/   .. you should get a red background on your iphone 3, a yellow background on your iphone 4, a blue background on a screen smaller than 767px and an orange background on a regular desktop screen. Tell me what are your results

Comment: The iPhone 4 landscape is not working ! Aren't others facing this issue ? If so, is there any fix for this ?

Comment: @sanz had the same color for both portrait and landscape, all fixed now (tested it on my iphone4). [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/SpbC3/4/show/)

Answer (score 1):

Great answer on using the colors to detect device and orientation.   iPhone 4 did not work though and only rendered as either green or purple backgrounds.

I found this article which shed some light.
http://www.hemmachat.com/2011/04/21/iphone-website-for-good-beginnings/

Now using the pixel ratio of 2 instead I can now get red and brown on an iPhone 4.

```
/* iPhone 4 portrait */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    body {
        background-color:red;
    }
}

/* iPhone 4 landscape */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 480px){
    body {
        background-color:brown;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

```
/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not currently support `orientation:portrait` and `orientation:landscape`.
Instead Apple currently uses the following:

**Portrait**
orientation:0
orientation:180 (not currently supported on iphone)

**Landscape**
orientation:90
orientation:-90

Ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/DataManagement/Reference/DOMWindowAdditionsReference/DOMWindowAdditions/DOMWindowAdditions.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this link   http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/SpbC3/4/show/ in the responsive test tool like http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ and `http://ipadpeek.com` .I have seen the landscape and the portrait mode displaying the same view. Is there any problem with those tools?